# syntax for dynamic controls? in asp.net and vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Welp, I'm frustrated now.. partly because I'm new to asp and this seems so simple and I cant get it to work but have in vb several times.

I've volunteered for a simple webform survey for customers and I've stuck on creating dynamic controls/ lables for the questions.. The number of questions will vary so I'd hate to change this webform everytime.

I'm stumbling over lines 6, 8 & 10: QuestionLabel1.Text = SQLRead.GetString(0) 
I'd rather do something like this: 
   QuestionLabel(cntr).Text = SQLRead.GetString(0) 
or
   ("QuestionLabel" & cntr).Text = SQLRead.GetString(0)
or even 
   Me.Controls.Add("QuestionLabel" & cntr)

```
For cntr = 1 To 5
    Dim QuestionLabel As New Label()
    Dim Panel1 As New Panel()
    Me.Controls.Add(QuestionLabel)
    QuestionLabel.ID = "QuestionBox" & cntr
    QuestionLabel1.Text = SQLRead.GetString(0)
    SQLRead.Read()
    QuestionLabel2.Text = SQLRead.GetString(0)
    SQLRead.Read()
    QuestionLabel3.Text = SQLRead.GetString(0)
```

I know that the syntax is wrong but I'm hoping you guys can look it over, get a sense of what I'm trying to accomplish and tell me if asp.net will allow this and if so what I'm missing.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're utilizing .ascx for your client scripting and vb.net for your code-behind. You should consider using a [Repeater](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp) control. It's designed specifically for things like this (adding controls dynamically). This architecture would allow you to 
use the knowledge you already have to create your SQL statements, and combine it with a 
relatively simple ASP approach.